# The "package.xml" file does not exist; please verify the archive

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to upload my plugin to the Magento Marketplace but it keeps giving the following error:

> The "package.xml" file does not exist; please verify the archive.

I have the package.xml file in the root of the archive along side the `app` and `skin` folders. Do i have the package.xml file in the correct place?

Comment: Where do I need to place the package.xml file after generation? I generated the file correctly using the Package Extension, and then tried to submit the extension placing this file in the root of my folder structure, and also tried inside a var/connect folder, but I'm still getting "The "package.xml" file does not exist; please verify the archive." Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It will be better if you share your package.xml file, otherwise it is possible there are some errors in your package.xml file and causing unreadability at magento end.

Try to create package.xml from where you package a Magento 1 extension:

```
System > Magento Connect > Package Extension
```

Your package.xml file will contain information:

1. name
2. version
3. stability
4. license
5. channel
6. summary
7. description, etc..

So try to create package.xml from above and check if contains all information. After that try to upload it on magento, it should work.